# last nested route throws error on mount of the compontent that holds the nested router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, router

I have strange behavior with nested routes.

I have a component on the homeview in which a nested route is displayed if necessary. This component is triggered via v-if!

inside HomeFloater

```
<transition name="fadepage" mode="out-in" appear key="store.state.kidsGames">
     <HomeFloater v-if="store.state.homeFloter==true" ></HomeFloater>  
</transition>
```

inside KidsGameView

```
    <router-view  v-slot="{ Component }">  
         <transition name="slidefade" appear mode="out-in" >
           <component :is="Component" class="animated" :key="route.path" />
         </transition>
    </router-view>


 onMounted(() => {

      
      console.log("onMounted");
      router.push( {name:"NestedView1"} );

....
```

If I now browse through different nested views within this component and then delete these parnet components, all unmounted hooks are triggered as expected.

But if I now display these parent components again and want to display the first nested view, the unmount of the last view is triggered and throws an error. Of course I can intercept this, but why does this happen?

Can I reset the nested route in the router before opening the components?

It doesn't happen if I leave the homeView in the parent router from time to time.